# mysqli insert row id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to learn PHP & Mysqli and ran into a few problems when trying to echo/print row id (or in this case "ref") as H2 (where it says "FORM").

Also when I add a new row it should get the next id in the database.

I hope that makes sense.

Sorry if this has already been posted. Couldn't find it.

```html
<?php
//server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'host');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '****');
define('DB_NAME', 'database');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
die('could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);

if (!$db_selected) {
die('Cant use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$value_1 = $_POST['column_1'];
$value_2 = $_POST['column_2'];
$value_3 = $_POST['column_3'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO maskiner (column_1, column_2, column_3) VALUES ('$value_1', '$value_2', '$value_3')";

if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    die('ERROR: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>FORM</h2>
        <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Column_1</label>
                <input type="text" name="column_1"class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value_1; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>      
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Column_2</label>
                <input type="text" name="column_2"class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value_2; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Column_3</label>
                <input type="text" name="column_3"class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value_3; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "ran into a few problems": what are those problems? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is it possible to echo/print the row ID into the HTML header and if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand properly your problem, but please try to create your table in your database using

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `your table` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

this way, your ID row will auto increment, and you don't have to feed the value

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you need last insert id. If that true, you sould use fallowing code

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

Above code gets last inserted increment id.

Note: Your id column in your table, it have to been increment property

Comment: I think thats what I'm looking for but for some reason it says "0" in the header when I insert you code and echo $last_id?

Comment: You have to use above code after your insert code. That should return last insert id

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know in advance the next id, you can't use

```
$next_id = mysqli_insert_id($link)+1;
```

because when you close mysql connection the next time you use mysqli_insert_id() you get 0.

You can use the query: select max(id)+1 as  next_id from maskiner; , but if you delete the last inserted row you'll get a wrong id. To avoid that you can assign next_id in the sql insert statement:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO maskiner (id, column_1, column_2, column_3) VALUES ('$next_id','$value_1', '$value_2', '$value_3')";
```